# Why .\Turorial.exe can run but Tutorial.exe not on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmake

I'm new for cmake, and try run the cmake example.

Compiling process is all normal, but when I run `Tuturial.exe 5` on **powershell**, got error as follows:

> Suggestion [3,General]: The command django-admin was not found, but
> does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load
> commands from the current location by default. If you trust this
> command, instead type: ".\django-admin". See "get-help
> about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

But run `.\Tutorial.exe 5`, everything is ok.

So I want know why this error happens, and if I want learn more what things should I learn?

Note: run `Tuturial.exe 5` on **cmd** is also normal.

Comment: This is a property of the shell (PS and CMD are different shells), there's nothing else to it. `.` refers to the current directory, and ``\`` is the path separator. You'll find that in the Linux world, most shells require `./` (since the path separator is `/` rather than ``\`` there).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a malicious command named `foo` in the current directory, unbeknownst to you, and you also have the command `foo` installed on your system. If you tried to run the (system) command `foo`, it would instead run the malicious program. So, in a nutshell, it is for security reasons, as it protects you from running unintended programs, and this is the reason that PowerShell (and almost all of Linux, as HolyBlackCat pointed out) forces you to use a `./` or `.\` in front of your program name.

This is pointed out and explained in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-dot-slash-to-execute-a-file-in-linux-unix) question.